# Raw USB socket?

Tags: usb, driver

Does anyone know how to create a raw socket to a USB device?  Like you can create raw sockets to ethernet devices, I would like to send/receive arbitrary data to a USB device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the platform - you need a low level USB library.

Either http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/  or  http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/ is a good place to start

ps. It isn't a socket as such, sockets are specific to networks

Comment: Are you aware if libusb has been used to establish faux sockets to USB connected IrDA devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the EndPoint using a Raw Socket but a certain protocol needs to be followed for the device to physically accept and reply to commands.

Depending on how the protocol is written you may be able to use a a RawSocket and some Usb sniffer to replay the data to the EndPoint but most devices employ a Timestamp and handshake process which needs to be performed dynamically for each connection and usually involves querying the device state and using the information to complete the handshake along with other information depending on the protocol of the device in question.